# nvm problems on Mac OSX

Tags: nvm

When I successfully installed nvm on Mac, I also activated nvm `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`.

When I run `commmand -v nvm`, I also can output nvm.

However, when it comes to nvm install node, terminal alerts:

> nvm needs curl or wget to proceed.

How to fix it?

Comment: install curl or wget ...

Comment: Assuming you have `brew` installed: `brew install wget`

Comment: Is it possible not to have cURL on a mac? (WIthout actively removing it)

Comment: Answering to all above,it's not the `wget` or `curl` problem, I've already installed them before

Comment: Add the answer as an answer below rather than editing your post!